# A server side node module for logging user device types

Tags: monitoring, node.js

I'm [working on a feature rich browser based web application](https://geoart.hyperactive.media) - and I'm going to want to know what devices my users are using, to know if it's worth accommodating iPhone5 for example.

At a basic level, I just want to log the device type for each person accessing the page.

Better - would be to be able to log more involved statistics - how long they stayed on the page, what actions they did, and differentiating between repeat visitors and one-time visitors.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel to do this. I want this to be as easy as possible.

Is there an existing nodejs framework that will allow me to collect this kind of data?

Comment: awstat is the references for web analyser, it need python

Comment: I suppose you have apache httpd in front of node (as proxy). So use apache logs